# Multiple Index Array - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

i have a project of a game, in it i need to impress the letter selected if the letter selected is present in the secret word, but when i try to catch the index of the select letter, like "a", in the secret word "programador, the code returns me all the index of the word "programador" not only the index where the letter "a" is present.

```
palavra_secreta = "programador"
letra_procurada = "a"
total_encontrado = palavra_secreta.count letra_procurada

palavra_secreta_array = palavra_secreta.split("")
puts palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra_procurada, index| 
  total_encontrado >= 1 
}.map { |pair| pair[1] }
```

this code is returning me: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `total_encontrado` is `2`, which is greater than or equal to `1`. As a result, the condition you give to `#select` is always true, so it selects every character with its index. You then map that to just the indices.

Instead, you likely want to select only the letters that match `letra_procurada`.

```
palavra_secreta = "programador"
letra_procurada = "a"
total_encontrado = palavra_secreta.count letra_procurada

palavra_secreta_array = palavra_secreta.split("")
puts palavra_secreta_array
     .each_with_index
     .select { |letra, index| letra_procurada == letra }
     .map { |pair| pair[1] }
```

You could also use `#filter_map` (Ruby 2.7 and later) to simplify this.

```
palavra_secreta = "programador"
letra_procurada = "a"
total_encontrado = palavra_secreta.count letra_procurada

palavra_secreta_array = palavra_secreta.split("")
puts palavra_secreta_array
     .each_with_index
     .filter_map { |letra, index| index if letra_procurada == letra }
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with problems where an array of indices of a collection or string whose corresponding elements satisfy a particular condition is to be returned, it is often convenient to work with an array of indices `[0,1,..,n]`. For example, if one wanted to return an array of indices of elements of the array `arr = [3,2,6,5,4]` that are odd numbers, one might write one of the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
arr.each_index.select  { |i| arr[i].odd? }
(0..arr.size-1).select { |i| arr[i].odd? }
arr.size.times.select  { |i| arr[i].odd? }
```

All return `[0, 3]`.

For the present problem, involving a string, we could use either of the last two approaches above:

```
(0..palavra_secreta.size-1).select { |i| palavra_secreta[i] == letra_procurada }
palavra_secreta.size.times.select { |i| palavra_secreta[i] == letra_procurada }
```

Both return `[5, 7]`.

I believe this approach reads well, as it should be immediately apparent to the reader that a selection of indices is being returned.

<sup>1. I realize that in #2 I could have written `(0...arr.size)`, but I have found that mixing two- and three-dot ranges tends to spawn bugs, so I only use three-dot ranges when a two-dot range cannot be used.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The condition inside your `select` clause will be true for every index, since it only checks the `total_encontrado` variable and that value will not change in each iteration.

```rb
puts palavra_secreta_array
  .each_with_index
  .select { |letra_procurada, index| total_encontrado >= 1 }
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  .map { |pair| pair[1] }
```

What you want is to select the indexes that match the guessed character, so your condition could do that instead:

```rb
puts palavra_secreta_array
  .each_with_index
  .select { |letra, index| letra == letra_procurada }
  .map { |pair| pair[1] }
```

Note that I had to change the name of the first parameter to the `select` block. You had re-used `letra_procurada` there, but that would have the effect of [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the actual `letra_procurada` variable. Remember that `select` is calling the block for each element in the array and *selecting* only the elements for which the that block returns true, so the first parameter to the block is the element from the array and, if you shadow or ignore it, you'll have no idea what you're dealing with inside the block.

You can also slim this down a bit more and skip the `split` in favor of using `String#each_char`:

```rb
puts palavra_secrata
    .each_char
    .with_index
    .select { |c, _| c == letra_procurada }
    .map(&:last)
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, `#filter_map` is a nice way to avoid using both `#select` and `#map`.

Answer (score 0):

`"letra_procurada"` means "letter wanted", so you seem to be under the impression that you have to *pass* the element you're looking for to select like this:

```
letra_procurada = "a"

palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra_procurada, index| }
#                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, this is not at all how block arguments or `select` in particular work. If you would replace `letra_procurada` by a string literal, you'd get a `SyntaxError` right-away:

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |"a", index| }
# SyntaxError: unexpected string literal
```

A block contains code that the method you pass the block to (here: `select`) can invoke (multiple times, just once or not at all). Upon each block invocation, the block arguments (`|letra_procurada, index|`) are passed *from* the method (i.e. from `select`) *into* the block.

You call `select`, but `select` calls the block. This is also known as a "[callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))".

In your example, `select` invokes the block for each element and passes that element as the block arguments `letra_procurada` and `index`. It then expects the block to return either `true` or `false`. That return value determines whether or not that element will be included in the result.

Since the block's first argument can be *any* letter, you likely want a more general variable name. Something like this:

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra, index|
   # ...
}
```

Some examples might help to understand this. To select only elements with an [`odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#odd-3F-method) index:

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra, index|
   index.odd?
}
#=> [["r", 1], ["g", 3], ["a", 5], ["a", 7], ["o", 9]]
```

To select only elements whose letter is equal to `"r"` or equal to `"o"`: (`||` means "or")

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra, index|
   letra == "r" || letra == "o"
}
#=> [["r", 1], ["o", 2], ["r", 4], ["o", 9], ["r", 10]]
```

Or combined, to select only elements with a letter of `"r"` or `"o"` and an odd index: (`&&` means "and")

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra, index|
  (letra == "r" || letra == "o") && index.odd?
}
#=> [["r", 1], ["o", 9]]
```

As you can see, using a block is a very flexible and powerful way to select elements.

Back to your problem. Your current block just checks whether `total_encontrado` is larger or equal to `1`. It doesn't take the current letter or its index into account. And because `total_encontrado` *is* larger than `1`, the block *always* returns `true` and `select` returns *all* elements.

To select only elements whose letter match the wanted letter `letra_procurada`, you'd use:

```
palavra_secreta_array.each_with_index.select { |letra, index|
   letra == letra_procurada
}
#=> [["a", 5], ["a", 7]]
```